# Make sure my userform does not edit other workbooks

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks that need to be open at the same time. Each has their own respective userforms that edit their respective databases, is there a way to make sure that Workbook A does not mess with Workbook B? I tried referencing it on workbooks but then it does not see to acknowledge workbooks(Published Articles Tracker v3.0.xlsm) reference.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook)  always returns the workbook in which the code is stored which is currently running.

Comment: Thanks, Axel, I think I'll try that for now. Cheers! But also if you can help with this then I think this will really resolve my enquiry: I want to write a code that will unload my userform every time I move to other windows. Can you help with that too?

Comment: Please don't tack on a question in a comment. As a new user, you may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Don't ignore that if you expect to get help here.

Comment: Sorry, I will take note.

Comment: this is resolved. Is there a button that I can click to confirm that my question is answered? Also, I want to give kudos to Alex if that's possible. Sorry, new fish here